# How to set a text from my AsyncTask to a textview in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, textview

Sooo here is my OnCreateView code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    tvMemberName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
    UrlPostHelper uph = new UrlPostHelper();
    uph.execute();
    return v;
}
```

and AsyncTask

```
    private class UrlPostHelper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/MP/Profile";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response;
        String data = "no response";
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String s = "yow";


        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0 ; i < ja.length(); i++ ){
                JSONObject j = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                String firstName = j.getString("firstName");
                String lastName = j.getString("lastName");
                System.out.println(firstName);
                s = firstName +" " + lastName;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("TAG", result );
        tvMemberName.setText(result);
    }


}
```

My problem is that in my android app it does not show anything at first but after a while like around 1-2 minutes the "yow" will show. It is not replaced with the member name though. I tried running my servlet and it works just fine. Please help me.

Comment: What is the value of 'result' in onPostExecute?

Comment: what response getting in `data` from servlet?

Comment: I guess, you just get JSONException. Check LogCat for the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

- `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`.

  ```
  private class UrlPostHelper extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
  private EditText tvMemberName;
  public UrlPostHelper(EditText tv){
    this.tvMemberName = tv;
  }
  ```
- Return Text after background task finished.

  ```
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

  HttpResponse response;
  String data = "no response";
  try {
      response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
      data = getJSONString(response.getEntity());
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

     return data; //Text to set TvMember Value
  }
  ```
- Get String from response Util.

  ```
  public String getJSONString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  String inputLine;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(inputLine);
  }
  in.close();
  return response.toString();
  }
  ```
- Set EditText onPostExecute.

  ```
  protected void onPostExecute(String result){
     Log.i("TAG", result );
     tvMemberName.setText(result);
  }
  ```
- Pass EditText with the UrlPostHelper call.

  ```
  new UrlPostHelper(tvMemberName).excute();
  ```